# `this` in callback functions

Tags: javascript

I used to use

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod1 = function(value) {
    this._current = this.getValue("key", function(value2){
        return value2;
    });
};
```

How do I access the value of this within the callback function like below?

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod1 = function(value) {
   this.getValue("key", function(value2){
       //ooopss! this is not the same here!    
       this._current = value2;
   });
};
```

Comment: you could always pass `this` over as a second argument. Not sure if it would work though.

Comment: It really does not have anything to do with whether a function is anonymous or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod1 = function(value) {
    var that = this;
    this.getValue("key", function(value2){
         //ooopss! this is not the same here!
         // but that is what you want
         that._current = value2;
    });

};
```

Or you could make your `getValue` method execute the callback with [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) set to the instance (using [`call`/`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#call_and_apply)).

Answer (score 2):

Declare a variable in the external scope to hold your this :

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod1 = function(value) {
    var that = this;
    this.getValue("key", function(value2){
         that._current = value2;
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare it as a variable before

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod1 = function(value) {
var oldThis = this;
 this.getValue("key", function(value2){
    /// oldThis is accessible here.
    });

};
```