# instance function variable is not changed?

Tags: javascript

I tried to console variable fullName after function run ,but it doesn't changed value ,just console default value `Not Set`,why was that?

```
function Test() {
    this.clientData = {
        fullName : "Not Set",
        setUserName: function (firstName, lastName) {
            this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
        },
        getUserInput2: function (firstName, lastName, callback) {
            callback(firstName, lastName);
        }
    };

    this.getUserInput1 = function (firstName, lastName, callback) {
        callback(firstName, lastName);
    };
}

var test = new Test();

test.getUserInput1("A1", "B1", test.clientData.setUserName);

console.log("test.clientData.fullName : " + test.clientData.fullName);//Not Set
//expected => A1 B1

test.clientData.getUserInput2("A2", "B2", test.clientData.setUserName);
console.log("test.clientData.fullName : " + test.clientData.fullName);//Not Set
//expected => A2 B2
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [*`this` in callback functions*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561723/this-in-callback-functions). Also you might like to read [*How does the “this” keyword work?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work/3127440#3127440) and [*MDN: this*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working. you can do this without using bind() function. you just need to store Test object in variable.

```js
function Test() {
 var t = this
 this.clientData = {
          fullName : "Not Set",
          setUserName: function (firstName, lastName) {
          t.clientData.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
          },
          getUserInput2: function (firstName, lastName, callback) {
              callback(firstName, lastName);
          }
       };
 this.getUserInput1 = function (firstName, lastName, callback) {
     callback(firstName, lastName);
       };
 }

var test = new Test();
test.getUserInput1("A1", "B1", test.clientData.setUserName);
console.log("test.clientData.fullName : " + test.clientData.fullName);//Not Set
//expected => A1 B1
test.clientData.getUserInput2("A2", "B2", test.clientData.setUserName);
console.log("test.clientData.fullName : " + test.clientData.fullName);//Not Set
```

Comment: I think you'd want that to be `var t = this;`

Answer (score 3):

It is because when the callbacks are called, the context(`this`) value of the callback is not the `clientData` object.

You can set the callback manualy using [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```js
function Test() {
  this.clientData = {
    fullName: "Not Set",
    setUserName: function(firstName, lastName) {
      this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    },
    getUserInput2: function(firstName, lastName, callback) {
      callback(firstName, lastName);
    }
  };
  this.getUserInput1 = function(firstName, lastName, callback) {
    callback(firstName, lastName);
  };
}

var test = new Test();
var userInput = new test.getUserInput1("A1", "B1", test.clientData.setUserName.bind(test.clientData));
snippet.log("test.clientData.fullName : " + test.clientData.fullName); //Not Set
//expected => A1 B1
test.clientData.getUserInput2("A2", "B2", test.clientData.setUserName.bind(test.clientData));
snippet.log("test.clientData.fullName : " + test.clientData.fullName); //Not Set
//expected => A2 B2
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Explain a bit about `.bind()`..+1

Comment: A function's *this* is but one parameter of its execution context, it's not **the** context. The OP's issue is that the callback's *this* isn't set to the right value, so that is what must be fixed (through bind, a closure or changing the call).

Answer (score 3):

To understand clearly about the `this` statement, you must understand that it represents the current "scope" inside the function.

When you declare :

```
function Test() {
    this.clientData = {
    ....
    };
}
```

`this` represents the current scope of the `Test` function. That's why, when you will do `var test = new Test();`, you will be able to use `test.clientData` and then get access to data you set in the initialization of your object.

Now, inside your `clientData` property of your `test` object, you have a `setUserName` (I recommend you to name it `setFullName`) which is again a function ([JavaScript is function scoped](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)). So if we look at your code :

```
function Test() {
    this.clientData = {
        fullName: "Not Set",
        setFullName: function(firstName, lastName) {
            /*
             * `this` represents the scope of the `setFullName` function,
             *  and not the scope of the `Test` function
             */
            this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName; 
        }
    };
}
```

So the trick is to store `this` in a variable in the top level, because JavaScript is function scoped, the variable will be available for every function inside the scope. So now we can do that :

```
function Test() {
    var self = this;
    self.clientData = {
        fullName: "Not Set",
        setFullName: function(firstName, lastName) {
            self.clientData.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName; 
        }
    };
}
```

I recommend you, to split your data and your method in a different way. Now you put everything in a `clientData` object that add some complexity to your app. You can separate the stored values (name, age, any storage information) and the methods that will interact with the data.

I suggest something like that :

```js
function Person() {
    var self = this;
    self.fullName = "Not Set"
    self.setFullName = function(firstName, lastName) {
        self.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName; 
    };
}
var john = new Person();
john.setFullName("John", "Doe");
console.log("john.fullName : " + john.fullName); // Display : John Doe
var bruce = new Person()
bruce.setFullName("Bruce", "Wayne");
console.log("bruce.fullName : " + bruce.fullName); // Display : Bruce Wayne
```

This way you have a much easier code to read and a much easier code to execute. After, it is up to you to organize and design your object logic the way you want to.

Hope it helps.